# Fatal execution error when a file is opened, closed and disposed multiple times in C#

Tags: c#, io

In a thread, a file is being opened, closed and disposed continuosly. Does this cause an issue ?

Here is the code

```
 StreamWriter file1 = new StreamWriter(filepath4, true);
                        for (int i = 0; i < ChannelValueForTcp; i++)
                        {
                            file1.WriteLine(data[i]);
                        }
                                file1.WriteLine(data[data.Length-1]);
                                file1.WriteLine(data[data.Length - 2]);
                                file1.Close();
                                file1.Dispose();
```

[image]

Please help I am stuck. (This comes up randomly we are trying to run the code for 8 hours continuously.)

Edit:

No no other thread works or does anything associated with this file. It is being used only here. 
There are other threads running, which are giving the same error but randomly after 45 minutes - 5 hours of testing.

[Here is the c code. Please download it](http://www.test.uberindia.org/ccode.txt)

```
[DllImport("ConsoleApplication2.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int main_c();

 public string[] tcp(string peer, int port)
        {

            int i = main_c();//the c code writes to a file called akash.txt and returns = 0 if it is successful. Then I read the file and do some functions on it. 

 if (i == 0)
            {
                StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader("akash.txt");
```

Comment: Do you have any `unsafe` code?

Comment: The StreamWriter implements IDisposable, so you want to wrap it in a using block as opposed to calling Close and Dispose yourself, although as @JonSkeet has pointed out, this isn't going to cause your error, it's just good practice.

Comment: Does this error always occurs on this exact code line? do you have other threads in the background that performs something related?

Comment: No. The error does not come here everytime. But out of 8-10 times that error has come, 2 times it was here.

Comment: Are you running the application from a file share? Ie. are the files of your applications (.exe, .dll's) located on a file share on a different machine than the one that is running it?

Comment: @bouvierr yes we do have some unsafe code i.e. we are using a dll implemented in c by us.

Comment: The dll with the unsafe code is the top priority then, probably overwrites memory or destroys the stack, I'd start with that.

Comment: You should probably show the C# declarations of the functions in the dll, along with the C declarations of the same, so that people here more versed in those things can help you figure out what happens. I'm 99.9% positive it's the unsafe code that is the culprit here.

Comment: You need to show how `main_c` is declared in C as well.

Comment: The next thing you need to do is go over all the C code and verify that you're not tripping on memory, like stuffing too much data into arrays or what not. This, unfortunately, is something you're probably going to have to do yourself since it's unrealistic that someone will read all that C code and try to figure out how everything works. If nothing else, I would add asserts to ensure that the code will crash with a known and descriptive exception if it encounters this, and use this for troubleshooting purposes until you figure out where the problem is.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen alright thanks will go through it a little more. As you said I will look out for places where I might be adding excess values to a array or something else.

Comment: For instance, the `res` buffer you're receiving into has been allocated with a "max receive size", but you're not actually verifying that the data you get back fit into the buffer, the loop to read until end of line for instance.

Comment: Did you tried  using **using statement** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Random crashes and FatalExecutionEngineError exceptions are normally associated with stack or heap corruption which can remain hidden until further down in your code. Ensure that you have marshalled all your C++ functions correctly using the right calling convention, parameter types and return types.

Microsoft specifies the probable cause of the message is:

> > The CLR has been fatally corrupted. This is most often caused by data corruption, which can be caused by a number of problems, such as calls to malformed platform invoke functions and passing invalid data to the CLR.

Judging from the code you've supplied, your declaration looks correct so it could be another function that you've marshalled that is causing an issue.

Ensure that your C++ code is stable and not the cause of the problem. I think that it might be associated with the deletion or filling of the 'res' buffer.

You could be compiling the DLL with a flag which sets the calling convention to something apart from __cdecl. You can verify this by right-clicking on the project > Properties > C/C++ > Advanced > Calling Convention.